# how to force footer to print only first page in jasper report and doen't consume any space from following page

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to print page footer at only first page. I have tried using print when expression $V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1.It prevent content to print on 2nd page onward 
but it consume the spaces.
Please note I am using IReport 5.6.0

Comment: What element of the report did you set with `printWhenExpression`? A code snippet from the JRXML will help.

Comment: P.s. iReport is several years old, did you try the latest Jaspersoft Studio? Lots of new features and improvements in the last few years ;)